# error on attempted translation of C++ Qt code to PyQt

Tags: qt, pyqt, translate

I am bulding a simple color picker, and I found an example [here](http://www.codeprogress.com/cpp/libraries/qt/showQtExample.php?key=QImageRGBPixelValue&index=557)
, however I would like to translate it to `PyQt` (please find my incomplete attempt below).

I am in particular having trouble translating the line:

```
QRgb rgba = palette().brush(QPalette::Background).textureImage().pixel(event->x(),event->y());
```

My translation attempt:

```
self.rgba = QtGui.qRgb
self.rgba = self.palette.brush(QtGui.QPalette.Background).textureImage().pixel(event.x(),event.y())
```

gives me the error:

```
QImage::pixel: coordinate (70,42) out of range
```

and my `print self.rgba` debug statement prints `12345`...

The example C++ code was written for `Qt5`, and I am using `PyQt4`. Would that be part of the problem?

### Original C++ code:

```
#include <QtWidgets>

class MyMainWindow:public QMainWindow
{
public:
  MyMainWindow()
  {
    setMouseTracking(true);
    setFixedSize(300,300);
  }
 ~MyMainWindow()
  {}

  void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent* event)
  {
    QRgb rgba = palette().brush(QPalette::Background).
          textureImage().pixel(event->x(),event->y());

    QString redComponent    = QString::number(qRed  (rgba));   
    QString greenComponent  = QString::number(qGreen(rgba));   
    QString blueComponent   = QString::number(qBlue (rgba));

    statusBar()->showMessage(" Red: "   +redComponent+
                 " Green: " +greenComponent+
                 " Blue: "  +blueComponent);
  }
};

int main(int argc,char** argv)
{  
  QApplication app(argc,argv);

  MyMainWindow window;  
  QImage image("penguin.jpg");
  QBrush brush(image);  
  QPalette palette;

  palette.setBrush(QPalette::Background,brush);
  window.setPalette(palette);  
  window.show();

  return app.exec();
}
```

### Translation to PyQt4 attempt (incomplete):

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore, uic


class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        # set mouse tracking
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        # load the ui
        uic.loadUi('main.ui', self)

        self.image = QtGui.QImage("color scale.png")
        self.brush = QtGui.QBrush(self.image)
        self.palette = QtGui.QPalette()

        self.palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Background, self.brush)
        self.setPalette(self.palette)
        self.show()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        self.rgba = QtGui.qRgb
        self.rgba = self.palette.brush(QtGui.QPalette.Background).textureImage().pixel(event.x(),event.y())
        print self.rgba


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

### Final working translated code:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore, uic


class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        # set mouse tracking
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        # load the ui
        uic.loadUi('main.ui', self)

        # load a statusbar for the main window
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(self)
        self.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        # load the image as the main window background
        self.image = QtGui.QImage("color scale.png")
        self.brush = QtGui.QBrush(self.image)
        self._palette = QtGui.QPalette()

        self._palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Background, self.brush)
        self.setPalette(self._palette)
        self.show()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        self.rgba = self.palette().brush(QtGui.QPalette.Background).textureImage().pixel(event.x(),event.y())
        self.red_component = QtCore.QString.number(QtGui.qRed(self.rgba))
        self.green_component = QtCore.QString.number(QtGui.qGreen(self.rgba))
        self.blue_component = QtCore.QString.number(QtGui.qBlue(self.rgba))
        self.statusBar().showMessage(
                                    "Red: " + self.red_component + 
                                    " Green: " + self.green_component + 
                                    " Blue: " + self.blue_component
                                    )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Not that I think this is the cause of your problem, but `QMainWindow` has a method `palatte()` which you are overriding with an attribute in your `__init__` method. You should store it in a variable with a different name (like `self._palette = QtGui.QPalette()`). Also the line `self.rgba = QtGui.qRgb` is pointless. You don't need it. Finally, if you do rename the variable as above, you should change your code to be `self.palette().brush(<etc>).<etc>` to be consistent with the c++ code.

Comment: your error message is telling you, that the coordinates are out of the image ... does it load and scale the image correct?

Comment: @Zaiborg I indeed had a scale problem due to the minimum size of the main window. I tried with another image, which cleared the error. Make that an answer, and I'll accept it.